# What's this problem with installing parity?

Tags: parity, mac-osx, installation

==> Checking out branch stable

> error: no such remote ref 403ff2e4759577d9e2b75b1389787a9c29670736
>   Fetched in submodule path '`ethcore/res/ethereum/tests`', but it did not contain 403ff2e4759577d9e2b75b1389787a9c29670736. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
>
> Error: Failed to download resource "parity"
>   Failure while executing: `git submodule -q update --init --recursive`
>
> Error: No such keg: `/usr/local/Cellar/parity`

==> Parity is missing

==> Installation failed

Comment: you can get tagged release versions here https://github.com/ethcore/parity/releases/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in one *(or more)* submodules - I've confirmed it myself on latest beta 1.3.8.

You can work around by:

- Download your desired release from https://github.com/ethcore/parity/releases/ *(you would probably want to go for 1.3.8 as chain has recently hard-forked)*
- run `cargo build --release && cp target/release/parity /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem as the OP.

error: no such remote ref cd2a6746bb653bf4b1acb6198b40df19ed8dde3b
Fetched in submodule path 'ethcore/res/ethereum/tests', but it did not contain cd2a6746bb653bf4b1acb6198b40df19ed8dde3b. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
Error: Failed to download resource "parity"
Failure while executing: git submodule -q update --init --recursive
-iMac:~ me$ parity version
Invalid arguments.

The response about tags was not clear and it didn't solve my problem.  Please be very clear on specific steps to take to solve the issue.  Thanks.